# Clojure parse JSON objects and extract specific key

Tags: clojure

Given I have a json file with the contents:

```
[
  {
    "email": "benb@mit.edu"
  },
  {
    "email": "aphacker@mit.edu"
  },
  {
    "email": "eval@mit.edu"
  },
  {
    "email": "prolog@mit.edu"
  },
  {
    "email": "bugs@mit.edu"
  },
  {
    "email": "morebugs@mit.edu"
  },
  {
    "email": "test@mit.edu"
  },
  {
    "email": "google@google.com"
  }
]
```

How can I parse this file and get the value for each `email` tag as I need to perform operations using the values.

Example:

Retrieve list of emails

`(benb@mit.edu, aphacker@mit.edu...)`

for each element in the list pass its value to a function. I understand how to pass it to a function, and have come across the `get-in` function but im not fully sure how to use it in this context.

Optionally, if possible I wish for the file to be stored

```
benb@mit.edu
aphacker@mit.edu
...
```

which will be more practical. I know how to write to a file and such but im not sure how to extract the email data.

Answer (score 3):

`slurp` [reads](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/slurp) the file into a string, then use a JSON parser (e.g. [cheshire](https://github.com/dakrone/cheshire) or [data.json](https://github.com/clojure/data.json)) to make it into a vector.  If you want to use the second file format, then [look](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/line-seq) at `line-seq` [or](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.string/split-lines) `split-lines`

Comment: I understand how to get the string from a file, I don't understand how to extract each `email` value from such string

Comment: @ChrisEdwards use the JSON parser, then if you're wanting to do something with each of them then use `doseq` to do so.  e.g. `(doseq [record (cheshire/parse-string (slurp filename))] (my-function (:email record)))`

Comment: do you want to post this as an answer so others can find it easier?

Comment: @ChrisEdwards I'm still not sure which part you were struggling with.  Parsing, iterating through the sequence, or getting the email from the record?

Comment: @iterating through the sequence was my issue

Comment: @ChrisEdwards if you update the question then I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Chris

You can read/parse the file as Dax pointed out and then, to address the other part of your question, once the maps are in a vector:

```
(def emails (map :email (json/read-str (slurp fully-qualified-file))))
```

will extract each each email into a sequence. You can then use something like the following to store the emails where each is a 'row' in the resulting file:

```
(spit fully-qualified-result-file (interpose "\n" emails))
```